# Why can't particle nature of light shows Young double slit experiment?

Tags: optics, waves, double-slit-experiment

I mean a single light ray can be comprise of many photon so its easy to understand the separation of light in two separate rays
No. Of photons are entering through ¹st slit and No. Of photon through second slit so how can we say that only wave nature of light can show **YDSE**
AND can somebody give me more examples of wave nature of light other than diffraction, polarisation
Is refraction and reflection there?

Comment: Do you have access to a spell checker?

Comment: Umm sorry for my bad english its my first time english and the site not support other language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the double slit experiment is done with a very low intensity light source, it is found that all the energy of each photon is absorbed at a single detector element. The electromagnet wave packet of each photon passes through both slits, and the recombination determines the probability that the energy will be absorbed at a particular location.